# No funciona correctamente .gitignore al versionar un proyecto Android

Tags: android, git, github

Aun no consigo tener un archivo .gitignore que pueda ayudar a mi código versionado en git para un proyecto en Android, si modifico una clase o algo muy sencillo se hacen modificaciones en archivos innecesarios como los test.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo mi .gitignore también.

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures

# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# Intellij
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries

# Keystore files
*.jks

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json
```

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes utilizar este sitio para generar un .gitignore "estandar" que se acomode a tus necesidades
https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: Para que el gitignore funcione correctamente, en el git no debe haber nada con ese nombre o ruta, de otro modo seguirá actualizando los archivos existentes con los cambios realizados. Si tienes algo en el git que no deba estar porque lo especificarás en el gitginore, eliminalo, haz el push, e inserta luego el gitignore.

Comment: De los archivos que muestras en la captura, si está bien que se versione el AndroidManifest.xml. Lo que no se debería versionar es la carpeta **build** dentro de **sample-core**. He agregado una respuesta sobre como excluir esa carpeta del control de versiones, espero te sirva

Comment: Rogelio, usaste un cliente o estas usando el bash? me refiero a  si estas usando comandos para estas operaciones? en el caso de usar un cliente regularmente genera automaticamente el -.gitignore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Revisa la [**documentación**](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore/1.6.0), donde especifica:

> Un archivo `gitignore` especifica intencionalmente archivos sin
>   seguimiento (untracked files) que git debe ignorar. Tenga en cuenta que todos los archivos de gitignore realmente se refieren solo a archivos que aún no han sido rastreados por git

Por lo tanto, lo definido dentro de `.gitignore` aplica para archivos sin
seguimiento, en tu caso los archivos que veo principalmente son los que se encuentran dentro de los directorios `/build` ya están marcados para seguimiento.

Para que tome los cambios realizados en el .gitignore realiza lo siquiente:

Realiza commit de cambios pendientes y remueve archivos modificados del indice:

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

guarda cambios:

```
git add .
```

y realiza un commit:

```
git commit -m ".gitignore funcionando!"
```

---

Revisando tu archivo `.gitignore`, te puedo sugerir algunos cambios:

- `*.iml` cambiar por `**/*.iml` para que busque en todos los directorios los archivos con extensión .iml
- `.gradle` por `.gradle/` especifica correctamente un directorio.
- Si especificas `/build`, no tienes que especificar los archivos `*.dex` y `*.class`, ya que se encuentran dentro de este directorio, lo mismo para los directorios `bin/` `gen/` (en android es `/generated`) y `out/` (en android es `/outputs`), no es necesario especificarlos.

Documentación 
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Gracias, es exacto lo que me mencionas, ya los pude eliminar de sa forma, ahora probare los cambios que me mencionas.

Answer (score 5):

El que agregues el archivo .gitignore al directorio no significa que va a ignorar asi por asi. Tienes correr los siguentes comandos para que gitignore reconoza los archivos que no deben de eser trackeados. **Recuerda darle commit a los archivos que tienes actualmente o sino perderás los cambios en esos archivos**

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Reparados archivos no trackeados"
```

Comment: falta agregar que tambien aplica para archivos que quitas del .gitignore

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema parece ser que que se está versionando la carpeta **sample-core/build/**

Para solucionar esto, a más del archivo `.gitnore` que tienes en la raíz de tu proyecto, deberías agregar un archivo `.gitignore` adicional dentro de tu carpeta **sample-core**. El archivo debería tener el siguiente contenido:

```
/build
```

Como dato adicional, cuando creas un nuevo proyecto con Android Studio, el IDE genera automáticamente estos dos archivos `.gitignore`: uno en la raíz del proyecto y otro dentro del módulo. [Aquí](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html) más información sobre la estructura de proyectos en Android.

Comment: el archivo .gitignore debe ir en la raiz del proyecto, ya que en la raiz existe un directorio /build.

Comment: Gracias al parecer tengo que eliminar a carpeta de sample core pero desde comando con git rm -r y luego git commit unto con el push, por que desde el sourcetree no me dejaba hacer commit.

Comment: @Jorgesys el .gitignore planteado en la pregunta contiene ya una entrada para /build, sin embargo falta una entrada para `/sample-core/build`. Podrías agregar una entrada `/sample-core/build` en ese mismo .gitignore que está en la raíz o la otra opción que planteo es crear un .gitnore adicional dentro de la carpeta sample-core y que debería tener la entrada `/build`