# ¿Como ignorar una carpeta cuando ya has realizado subidas?

Tags: git, sourcetree

Estoy con un proyecto en Django en el que necesito que git deje de contemplar las carpetas **pycache** y migrations de las distintas aplicaciones que tengo.

He modificado el gitignore para añadir todas las rutas que quiero ignorar pero al parecer si ya has realizado una subida no atiende a ese fichero y siempre me refleja los cambios para subirlos.

También tengo una carpeta llamada media en la que se añaden las imagenes que suben los usuarios.

ahora mismo tengo el fichero gitignore de la siguiente forma:

### GITIGNORE

```
manage.py
media/*
usuarios/migrations/*
usuarios/__pycache__/*
productos/migrations/*
productos/__pycache__/*
backend/migrations/*
backend/__pycache__/*
frontend/migrations/*
frontend/__pycache__/*
intranet/migrations/*
intranet/__pycache__/*
src/settings-prod.py
src/__pycache__/*
emojipy/__pycache__/*
api/__pycache__/*
src/aws/__pycache__/*
emojipy/__pycache__/*
```

He probado con el comando `git update-index --assume-unchanged carpeta/__pycache__/*` pero en algunas carpetas sigue mostrandome que hay cambios.

Comment: Este problema ya tiene una pregunta en este foro, mira la [respuesta de Jorgesys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112525/no-funciona-correctamente-gitignore-al-versionar-un-proyecto-android), la pregunta es para un proyecto en Android, pero en la respuesta los comando de GIT son generales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es eliminar esos archivos de la caché de `git`. Para hacerlo puedes utilizar este comando:

```
git rm --cached tu_archivo_o_directorio
```

Comment: Gracias, no sabía como podía hacerlo.