# Se ignora el archivo sin estar en el .gitignore

Tags: git

No puedo hacer ningún "git add" porque git no detecta ningun cambio en cualquier archivo que se llame `__init__.py`

He tratado de añadir nuevos archivos y tampoco me los detecta.

He tratado de añadir código dentro del archivo y tampoco detecta ningún cambio.

Si lo llamo `__init__2.py` entonces si que lo detecta.

Mi `.gitignore`:

```
# Distribution / packaging
.Python
*.pyc
env/
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
.idea/
node_modules/
# Serverless directories
.serverless
venv/bin/activate
venv/bin/activate.csh
venv/bin/activate.fish
venv/bin/activate.ps1
venv/bin/activate_this.py
venv/bin/easy_install
venv/bin/easy_install-2.7
venv/bin/pip
venv/bin/pip2
venv/bin/pip2.7
venv/bin/python
venv/bin/python-config
venv/bin/python2
venv/bin/python2.7
venv/bin/wheel
venv/include/python2.7
```

añado la estructura del proyecto:

```
repositorio
   |
   carpeta
        | __init__.py
        | carpeta
              | __init__.py
              | my_function.py
```

> El archivo no está dentro de `.gitignore` y me pasa con absolutamente
>   todos los repositorios (incluso si creo nuevos)

Comment: Tienes un .gitignore ? En caso afirmativo mira que no este puesto ahi.

Comment: mira esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/112558/28035

Comment: @JackNavaRow si si! acabo de hacerlo ya dos veces y estamos en las mismas! el ultimo paso, el commit, veo que me ha commiteado todos los __init__.py menos el que acabo de crear... Sigo en las mismas... Es muy frustrante esto.

Comment: @JackNavaRow acabo de añadir la estructura del proyecto en la pregunta.

Comment: @JackNavaRow da igual cual __init__.py quiera modificar. Me pasa con TODOS los __init__.py y me da igual en que repositorio esté. Me ocurre con TODOS los repositorios, incluso si creo uno nuevo. Es como si tuviera algo configurado en mi ordenador.

Comment: puedes que tengas un gitignore global , intenta ejecutar el comando `git config --global core.excludesfile` si te devuelve una ruta, pues tienes un gitignore global

Comment: En tu cuenta raíz de usuario (tu `$HOME`) tienes un fichero llamado `.gitconfig` que guarda configuraciones globales que afectarán a todos tus repositorios. Es un archivo de texto editable. Mira a ver si tienes algo en él que pueda estar causando esto.

Comment: @JackNavaRow SOLUCIONADO! tenia los __init__.py en el gitignore global! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: @abulafia SOLUCIONADO efectivamente este era el error. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @JackNavaRow hecho!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El archivo `__init__.py` se encontraba en el archivo global de `.gitignore` de mi $HOME por lo que me estaba ignorando TODOS los ficheros de este tipo.

Para localizar mi `.gitignore` global he ejecutado

```
git config --global core.excludesfile
```

y he editado el fichero.

Gracias a @JackNavaRow y a @abulafia.

Comment: genial que encontraras el error, hasta yo me estaba perturbando, te invito a visitar el sito el dia siguiente y marcar tu pregunta como aceptada, ganaras 2 puntos y futuros agradecimientos de otros usuarios de la comunidad

Comment: Sisi eso voy a hacer. Ahora no me deja pero dentro de dos días marco esta respuesta como correcta. Nuevamente muchas gracias!

Comment: Me queda el interrogante de cómo pudo llegar `__init__.py` a tu `.gitignore` global. No es un archivo que deba ignorarse en general, sin él los paquetes python dejan de ser paquetes válidos.

Comment: @abulafia es posible que sea cosa del IDE que estoy usando(pycharm) es posible que en algun momento lo haya ignorado de forma global por sugerencia del IDE. Si no no me lo explico.