# El archivo gitignore de GIT no ignora mi archivo .env de laravel

Tags: laravel, git

tengo un proyecto de laravel el cual en la raíz del proyecto hay un archivo llamado ".env", el problema es que aunque añado ese archivo al archivo gitignore de git los cambios que hago en dicho archivo aun siguen siendo seguidos [Imagen de proyecto laravel[image: imagen de giignore]por git, adjunto imagen de mi proyecto laravel y de mi archivo gitignore

Comment: Laravel por defecto ya tiene un .gitignore con el archivo .env. Lo habías quitado y ahora lo vuelves a agregar?

Comment: Solo ubique el archivo gitignore en la raíz del proyecto y añadí .env pero igual los cambios que hago se siguen detectando por git

Comment: Puedes sacarlo del índice con `git rm --cached .env`. Pero me parece raro, pues nunca debió empezar a seguir ese archivo. Mira el [.gitignore](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.gitignore) que trae laravel por defecto, ya sea que lo instales o lo clones, también está en la raíz del proyecto

Comment: Amigo me resolviste el problema muchas gracias!, aunque no logre que .gitignore me ignorara el archivo .env, con git rm --cached .env ya git no sigue los cambios a ese archivo. gracias que estés bien

Comment: Ok, lo comento como posible duplicado de [No funciona correctamente .gitignore](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112525/no-funciona-correctamente-gitignore-al-versionar-un-proyecto-android) ya que hay varias preguntas sobre el mismo tema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un limpiado de la caché de git y despues resubir los archivos, y ya deberia ignorarte el .env.

**Primero:**

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
```

**Despues:**

```
git commit -am "Remove ignored files"
```

Comment: Hola Alberto gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Me funciono poniendo en .gitignore de la siguiente manera:

/.env

Te daras cuenta que el archivo se opaca

Saludos